# order of non abelian group can't be what?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non abelian group; then its order can be:

1. $25$
2. $55$
3. $35$
4. $125$

I think the order cannot be $25$ and $35$. But from option $55$ and $125$ which one is not possible?

Why not $25$ because every group of order $p^2$ is abelian. Here $p$ is $5$. Why not $35$ because $35=5*7$ and $5$ does not divide $7-1$. There there is only one group which is cyclic up to isomorphism of order $35$.

Comment: you tried something??

Comment: $55$ and $125$ are both possible.

Comment: First of all mind your language.... I really do not see any thing other than "But from option 55 and 125 which one is not possible?" You did not said anything about what do you think about those groups....

Comment: @ketan why you think $|G|\neq 35$? what is the difference with $|G|=55$?

Answer (score 5):

1. $|G|=25$ is not possible since groups of order $p^2$ are always abelian.
2. $|G|=125$ is possible since for any prime $p$ there exist a non-abelian group of order $p^3$.
3. In a group of order $35$ the $7$ group and the $5$ group are normal by the Sylow theorems and hence this group is cyclic.
4. In a group of order $55$, the $11$-group is normal, but the $5$-group does not have to be normal and therefore there is a non-commutative group of order $55$.

Other words for $35,55$. In both cases the group must be a semi-direct product
$$C_q\rtimes C_p,$$
where $p<q$. In the case $q=7$ this action must be trivial since $5$ do not divide $7-1$. However, for $q=11$ there is a non-trivial action of $C_5$ on $C_{11}$ and therefore the group do not have to be commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
1)Note that $o(G)=5^2$,what do u know about groups of order $p^2$.

2)Note that $o(G)=5*11 $ what do u know about groups of order $pq$.

3)Note that $o(G)=5*7$ again what do u know about groups of order $pq$.

4)Note that $o(G)=5^3$,what do u know about groups of order $p^3$.

Added:1)Every group of order $p^2$ is abelian.

2,3)Suppose $o(G)=pq$, 
$p<q$ and p does not divide $q-1$ then every group of order $pq$ is cyclic.Suppose p divides $q-1$ then there is a unique nonabelian group of order $pq$,obviously upto isomorphism.

4)For any prime there exist a nonabelian group of order $p^3$,namely Heisenberg Group with entries from a field of order $p$.

Comment: What do we know about groups of order $pq$? Say on groups of order $6$?

Comment: obviously,there are at most two groups of order pq depending on p and q

Comment: @OfirSchnabel did u downvote? why someone downvote my answer?

Comment: I did because it was wrong and also you gave it before the OP show any effort of his own. Now your answer is good so I cancel my downvote.

Comment: Actually ,what was wrong?

Comment: From your original answer it looked like $35$ and $55$ are the same, you gave the same resoning.

Answer (score 1):

Take G=HF(5), Heisenberg group over feild of order 5 gives non Abelian group of order 125