# Let G be a non abelian group then its order can be...

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a non abelian group.Then , its order can be:(which will be correct options)
>  
>   $(1).~25$
>  $(2).~55$
>  $(3).~125$
>  $(4).~35$

I know ,what is abelian group,also I know order of a group.but I can't ans this question.
 Please help me.

Comment: I would like to see @Abhi make a bit more effort before receiving help.

Comment: This question has already been answered here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126354/order-of-non-abelian-group-cant-be-what

Comment: To both who corrected my false statement-- thanks, took comment down

Answer (score 1):

$25$ is impossible, groups of order $p^2$ are abelian because the center is not trivial (it is a $p$-group), this forces $G/Z(G)$ to be cyclic and hence $G=Z(G)$.

$55$ is possible, $5$ divides $11-1$, so we can build a non-trivial semidirect product $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_{11}$ (because there is a non-trivial morfism $\mathbb Z_5\rightarrow Aut(\mathbb Z_{11})\cong \mathbb Z_{10}$

$125$ is possible.  We can always find non-abelian groups of order $p^3$ by taking the [heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) with the ring $\mathbb Z_p$.

$35$ is impossible because $5\nmid 7-1$. So we can show with sylows theorem that both sylow p subgroups are normal and hence the group would be a direct product of $\mathbb Z_5$ and $\mathbb Z_7$